# How to get to Hierarchy View while running the app on my device connected to android studio

Tags: android-studio, ddms, hierarchyviewer

Okay, so I am trying to get to know the android studio and been playing with few projects. My question is how can I run or debug an app and then open the hierarchy view on it. If I try to open the Android Device Monitor, while the app is running, I get the message: "Following debug sessions will be closed:xx". I see a small Android DDMS window, which opens while debugging or running, where I see the options for Method tracing and allocation tracking, but what about Hierarchy view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the gui, but there are instructions for launching it from the cli, [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html).

> 4. From a terminal, launch hierarchyviewer from the `<sdk>/tools/`
>      directory.

You can determine your `<sdk>` directory in Android Studio via: 
File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location

Comment: Seems like that's all she wrote: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

execute the following:

`./Users/<YourUser>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer`

I've made an alias for it:

`alias viewer='./Users/<YourUser>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer'`

path might be different so locate it:

```
locate uiautomatorviewer
```